# Haskell equivalent of C# 5 async/await

Tags: c#, haskell, asynchronous

I just read about the new way to handle asynchronous functions in C# 5.0 using the `await` and `async` keywords. Examle from the [C# reference on await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx):

```cs
private async Task SumPageSizesAsync()
{
    // To use the HttpClient type in desktop apps, you must include a using directive and add a 
    // reference for the System.Net.Http namespace.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // . . .
    Task<byte[]> getContentsTask = client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    byte[] urlContents = await getContentsTask;

    // Equivalently, now that you see how it works, you can write the same thing in a single line.
    //byte[] urlContents = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    // . . .
}
```

A `Task<byte[]>` represents the Future of an asynchronous task that will generate a value of type `byte[]`. Using the keyword `await` on a `Task` will basically put the rest of the function in a continuation which will be called when the task is done. Any function that uses `await` must use the keyword `async` and have type `Task<a>` if it would return type `a`.

So the lines

```
byte[] urlContents = await getContentsTask;
// Do something with urlContents
```

would translate into something like

```
Task newTask = getContentsTask.registerContinuation(
               byte[] urlContents => {
                 // Do something with urlContents
               });
return newTask;
```

---

This feels a lot like a Monad (-transformer?). It feels like it should
have some relation to the CPS monad, but maybe not.

Here is my attempt at writing corresponding Haskell types

```hs
-- The monad that async functions should run in
instance Monad Async
-- The same as the the C# keyword
await         :: Async (Task a) -> Async a
-- Returns the current Task, should wrap what corresponds to
-- a async method in C#.
asyncFunction :: Async a -> Async (Task a)
-- Corresponds to the method Task.Run()
taskRun       :: a -> Task a
```

and a rough translation of the above example

```hs
instance MonadIO Async -- Needed for this example

sumPageSizesAsync :: Async (Task ()) 
sumPageSizesAsync = asyncFunction $ do
    client <- liftIO newHttpClient
    -- client :: HttpClient
    -- ...
    getContentsTask <- getByteArrayAsync client url
    -- getContentsTask :: Task [byte]
    urlContents <- await getContentsTask
    -- urlContents :: [byte]

    -- ...
```

Would this be the corresponding types in Haskell? Is there any Haskell library this (or a similar way) implements way to handle asynchronous functions/actions?

Also: Could you build this using the CPS-transformer?

### Edit

Yes, the [`Control.Concurrent.Async`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) module does solve a similar problem (and has a similar interface), but does so in an entirely different way. I guess that [`Control.Monad.Task`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-task) would be a closer match. What (I think) I am looking for is a monadic interface for Futures **that uses Continuation Passing Style behind the scenes**.

Comment: You can check out the haskel library `async` it should provide what you are looking for: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async

Comment: The `async` package is even better than the C# feature, since it removes the responsibility over really being asynchronous from the function being called. The only disadvantage I can see is performance, since `Control.Concurrent.Async` (probably) requires a lot more bookkeeping than the simpler solution in C#. Lightweight threads and STM is very heavy compared to glorified callbacks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a `Task` monad that builds on top of the `async` library:

```
import Control.Concurrent.Async (async, wait)

newtype Task a = Task { fork :: IO (IO a) }

newTask :: IO a -> Task a
newTask io = Task $ do
    w <- async io
    return (wait w)

instance Monad Task where
    return a = Task $ return (return a)
    m >>= f  = newTask $ do
        aFut <- fork m
        a    <- aFut
        bFut <- fork (f a)
        bFut
```

Note that I haven't checked the monad laws for this, so it might not be correct.

This is how you would define primitive tasks that run in the background:

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)

test1 :: Task Int
test1 = newTask $ do
    threadDelay 1000000  -- Wait 1 second
    putStrLn "Hello,"
    return 1

test2 :: Task Int
test2 = newTask $ do
    threadDelay 1000000
    putStrLn " world!"
    return 2
```

Then you can combine `Task`s using `do` notation which creates a new deferred task ready to be run:

```
test3 :: Task Int
test3 = do
    n1 <- test1
    n2 <- test2
    return (n1 + n2)
```

Running `fork test3` will spawn the `Task` and return a future which you can invoke at any time to demand the result, blocking if necessary until done.

To show that it works, I'll do two simple tests.  First, I'll fork `test3` without demanding its future just to make sure it spawns the composite thread correctly:

```
main = do
    fork test3
    getLine -- wait without demanding the future
```

This works correctly:

```
$ ./task
Hello,
 world!
<Enter>
$
```

Now we can test what happens when we demand the result:

```
main = do
    fut <- fork test3
    n   <- fut  -- block until 'test3' is done
    print n
```

... which also works:

```
$ ./task
Hello,
 world!
3
$
```

Comment: What would correspond to what keyword (Task<a>, await, async etc.) here?

Comment: The Haskell version's `newTask` would correspond to `C#` `async` and the Haskell verion's `wait` would correspond to C# `await`.  There is no perfect match to the Haskell version's `Task` type since `C#` uses the same type for both the task and the future it yields, so it is a little bit confusing.  Similarly, there is no C# equivalent to the Haskell version's `fork` since C# is basically implicitly calling `fork` for you behind the scenes every time you call a C# `Task`.

Comment: Afaik the `Task` type in C# is just the future and nothing else. And C# does not do an implicit fork, it implicitly registers a callback on the future values (the rest of the `async` function when using `await`), this has significant performance implications. All the forking is explicitly done by the functions that generated the original `Task`.

Comment: Though I take your point that the future type is a monad, you have misunderstood what the await operator does in C#. The point of await is not "fork off a new thread that performs this computation concurrently"!  The point of await is that it means "rewrite the current method into continuation passing style; evaluate the current task-returning expression, record the current continuation in that task, and return control to the caller".  When the task completes the continuation is scheduled.  That is very different from what you've written.

Comment: @EricLippert Yes, my description of `await` in C# was unclear/incorrect. Maybe I should not have tried to describe it in the question, as it seems to have lead to more confusion then clarification.

Comment: It sure feels like some of C#'s `async`/`await` is just `Monad` itself.

Comment: @EricLippert Your one-line summary of await is intriguing! Could you point to an expansion/elaboration of your one liner?

Answer (score 0):

The `monad-par` library provides `spawn` and `get` functios that can be used to create `Future`-like computations. You can either use the `Par` monad for pure code that would be run in parallel, or `ParIO` for code with side-effects.

In particular, I think that you're code example could be translated into:

```
import Control.Monad.Par.IO

sumPageSizesAsync :: URL -> IO ByteString
sumPageSizesAsync url = runParIO $ do
  task <- spawn $ liftIO $ do client <- newHttpClient
                              return $ getContents url
  urlContents <- get task
```

As you can see, `spawn` is the responsible for creating code that runs in parallel, and returns an `IVar` which can be later on queried by `get` for retrieving its answer. I think the behavior of those two functions match very well `async` and `await`.

For more information I recommend you reading the [`Par` monad chapter](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch04.html) of *Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell*.