# Asynchronous IO in Haskell

Tags: haskell, promise

So in C# there is the WWW class which you can use to load data from the web. To act on the object async I do three things.

1. Create a Promise Monad
2. fmap some tasks or functions into the Promise
3. Ship the Promise to a Coroutine (which waits for the load to finish and resolves the promise).

This works great! To code looks sync but the process is async. However, my C# implementation is based states so I get the result even if my Promised was resolved elsewhere.

With some help I implemented a [Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23899072/2118130) in Haskell, but I where to ship this "object" to a coroutine (really don't know how to do anything like that in Haskell) I would never see the fulfilled promise. Since there are no side effects then you don't get the results expressed elsewhere either.

How do you deal with this on Haskell?

Comment: Did you read [Parallel and Concurrent Programming in Haskell](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/index.html) yet? The second part implements `Async` in some variations.

Comment: [`async`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.0.1.5/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html) is probably the package you want to investigate.

Comment: Is this a C# or Haskell question? Please remove non-applicable tag.

Comment: Basically the way to do a `coroutine` like sync flow that is actually async is Haskell is simpler than it sounds, it's simply what `do` notation provides for us. There is also no explicit need for a promise type.

Comment: Usually when people want promises in Haskell they either want `async` or the continuation monad.

Comment: GHC's runtime already does async I/O behind the scenes. Just use `forkIO` to spawn a green thread, then communicate with it through chans.

Comment: Yeah, it's funny to hear about "async I/O" in a controlled state environment, in functional languages _everything_ is reactive, Haskell code simply doesn't _care_ if I/O is synchronous or not since functional composition and sequencing with monads does not depend on 'synchronous' I/O or not. I can hardly think of an environment _more_ appropriate for concurrency. If you want a conceptual PoV - imagine that in Haskell __almost everything__ is a promise, since whenever you're doing a `Task#ContinueWith` in C#, or a `Promise#then` in JavaScript, you're doing a monadic bind.

Comment: I develop in Unity3D, OOP in a Game Engine feels natural, but then you start integrating some FP (which I test on Haskell); what feels like spooky C# also feels like ultra-flexible Haskell. You wonder how would they do this on Haskell? I think sometimes the answer is: they didn't have to in the first place.
Anywhay, has somebody use FPcomplete?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20295604/haskell-equivalent-of-c-sharp-5-async-await

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of querying two servers, waiting for the responses, and `fmap`ing on the result of one of the requests. It looks like there is a `Functor` instance for the `Async` type ([Async definition](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.1/docs/src/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#Async)), but not a `Monad` instance.

```
module Main where

-- async
import Control.Concurrent.Async
-- HTTP
import Network.HTTP

mergeHTTPCode :: (Int, Int, Int) -> String
mergeHTTPCode (a,b,c) = show a ++ show b ++ show c

main :: IO ()
main = do
  a1 <- async $ do
    rsp <- Network.HTTP.simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://www.haskell.org/")
    getResponseBody rsp

  a2 <- async $ do
    rsp <- Network.HTTP.simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://www.duckduckgo.com/")
    getResponseCode rsp

  page1 <- wait a1
  page2 <- mergeHTTPCode <$> wait a2

  print page1
  print page2
```